# Pattern matching code in java

Tags: java, regex

I need to parse several rows of the type of JSON code given below. I need to remove all the commas(,) which are inside square brackets. That is `["Cheesesteaks","Sandwiches", "Restaurants"]` becomes `["Cheesestakes""Sandwiches""Restaurants"]`. I need to preserve all the other commas as they are.

Another example - `["Massachusetts Institute of Technology", "Harvard University"]` would become `["Massachusetts Institute of Technology""Harvard University"]` keeping all other commas intact.

```
{"business_id": "EjgQxDOUS-GFLsNxoEFJJg", "full_address": "Liberty Place\n1625 Chestnut St\nMantua\nPhiladelphia, PA 19103", "schools": ["Massachusetts Institute of Technology", "Harvard University"], "open": true, "categories": ["Cheesesteaks", "Sandwiches", "Restaurants"], "photo_url": "http://s3-media4.ak.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/SxGxfJGy9pXRgCNHTRDeBA/ms.jpg", "city": "Philadelphia", "review_count": 43, "name": "Rick's Steaks", "neighborhoods": ["Mantua"], "url": "http://www.yelp.com/biz/ricks-steaks-philadelphia", "longitude": -75.199929999999995, "state": "PA", "stars": 3.5, "latitude": 39.962440000000001, "type": "business"}
```

Can someone please help me find the regular expression to match this pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Pattern outer = Pattern.compile("\\[.*?\\]");
Pattern inner = Pattern.compile("\"\\s*,\\s*\"");
Matcher mOuter = null;
Matcher mInner = null;

mOuter = outer.matcher(jsonString);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

while (mOuter.find()) {
    mOuter.appendReplacement(sb, "");
    mInner = inner.matcher(mOuter.group());
    while (mInner.find()) {
        mInner.appendReplacement(sb, "\"\"");
    }
    mInner.appendTail(sb);
}
mOuter.appendTail(sb);

System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

And replace `jsonString` with your input.

Answer (score 0):

That should be a very simple replace.

```
String in = "[\"Cheesesteaks\",\"Sandwiches\", \"Restaurants\"]";
String out = in.replaceAll(", ?", "");
System.out.println(out);
```

Gives

```
["Cheesesteaks""Sandwiches""Restaurants"]
```